# How to assign Custom Redstone Textures?

Tags: java, minecraft

```
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public void registerBlockIcons(IIconRegister p_149651_1_)
{
    this.field_150182_M = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "cross");
    this.field_150183_N = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "line");
    this.field_150184_O = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "cross_overlay");
    this.field_150180_P = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "line_overlay");
    this.blockIcon = this.field_150182_M;
}

@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public static IIcon getRedstoneWireIcon(String p_150173_0_)
{
    return p_150173_0_.equals("cross") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150182_M :  (p_150173_0_.equals("line") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150183_N : (p_150173_0_.equals("cross_overlay") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150184_O : (p_150173_0_.equals("line_overlay") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150180_P : null)));
}
```

I am trying to make a custom redstone type but I don't know how to assign the textures. I copied the code from the original redstone file, but I'm having a hard time understanding it. I am getting errors in my `getRedstoneWireIcon()` method on all the `field_` terms. It is saying that it cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, you need to make sure that all your variables match up, like this:

```
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.IIconRegister;
import net.minecraft.util.IIcon;

class ModMain
{
    public static BluestoneWire bluestoneWire = new BluestoneWire();
}

public class BluestoneWire
{
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private IIcon field_150182_M;
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private IIcon field_150183_N;
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private IIcon field_150184_O;
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private IIcon field_150180_P;
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private IIcon blockIcon;

    public String getTextureName()
    {
        return "bluestoneWire";
    }

    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public void registerBlockIcons(IIconRegister p_149651_1_)
    {
        this.field_150182_M = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "cross");
        this.field_150183_N = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "line");
        this.field_150184_O = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "cross_overlay");
        this.field_150180_P = p_149651_1_.registerIcon(this.getTextureName() + "_" + "line_overlay");
        this.blockIcon = this.field_150182_M;
    }

    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public static IIcon getRedstoneWireIcon(String p_150173_0_)
    {
        return p_150173_0_.equals("cross") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150182_M : (p_150173_0_.equals("line") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150183_N : (p_150173_0_.equals("cross_overlay") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150184_O : (p_150173_0_.equals("line_overlay") ? ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_150180_P : null)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have copied those as well, but it still isn't working. The same error is coming up.

Comment: @Ved115 There's nothing wrong with what you posted, just make sure the code you didn't post matched up with above.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did, but its still giving me an error. I tried cleaning the project but it didnt work. Any other ideas?

Comment: field_150182_M cannot be resolved or is not a field, field_150183_N cannot be resolved or is not a field, field_150184_O cannot be resolved or is not a field, field_150180_P cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getRedstoneWireIcon` with this:

```
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public static IIcon getRedstoneWireIcon(String p_150173_0_)
{
    return p_150173_0_.equals("cross") ? field_150182_M :  (p_150173_0_.equals("line") ? field_150183_N : (p_150173_0_.equals("cross_overlay") ? field_150184_O : (p_150173_0_.equals("line_overlay") ? field_150180_P : null)));
}
```

You can't use `ModMain.bluestoneWire.field_` because each `field_` is private.